# Exporting localhost wordpress to live server

Tags: wordpress

How to export localhost wordpress to live server.

Answer (score 1):

Read the Docs: [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and [How to Move WordPress to New Domain or Location  »  My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/)

Answer (score 0):

Steps for uploading to your server from localhost-

1. Create backup of your worpdress files folder and create one zip file of that folder.
2. Take DB backup.
3. Uploading it to live server, i assume you are placing your content via `cpanel`.
4. Upload your zip file under file manager.
5. Upload database via Mysql wizard.
6. Change url from localhost to your URL by searching "localhost" keyword in your database.

If you face any problem let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1) Login to Local Wordpress > Dashboard > Tools > Export > All posts & Content (include attachments)

2) Login to Live Wordpress > Dashboard > Tools > Import > Wordpress > Install & Activate Wordpress Importer plugin > Select File > Finish

Comment: And how to handle images in the posts?